# Controlling the order of output with Org-Babel

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

Consider the following Org file:

```org
#+PROPERTY: tangle "init.el"
#+PROPERTY: noweb yes

* A
#+begin_src elisp
; initialization code
; this *must* come first
#+end_src

* B
#+begin_src emacs-lisp
<<support-functions>>
#+end_src

** Cool Stuff
#+begin_src elisp :noweb-ref "support-functions" :tangle no
(message "willkommen")
#+end_src

** Test
#+begin_src elisp :noweb-ref "support-functions" :tangle no
(message "hi")
#+end_src
```

yields

```el
(message "willkommen")
(message "hi")

; initialization code
; this *must* come first
```

yet removing the `:tangle` header argument on one of the blocks in `Cool Stuff` fixes the issue, but duplicates code:

```el
; initialization code
; this *must* come first

(message "hi")

(message "willkommen")
(message "hi")
```

What must I do to ensure correct behavior?  I know I *could* simply turn off tangling for the document and have everything be noweb, but this feels like a workaround rather than a solution.

Comment: Does this help? [Is it possible...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15711303/is-it-possible-to-call-org-babel-code-blocks-from-other-code-blocks)

Comment: @KingShimkus I've never used `var`iables in org-babel, but the other answers are almost exactly what I'm doing.

Comment: I know, I all the answers. Just thought the first answer might serve some use.

Comment: @KingShimkus Ah, well I'd like to not introduce ambiguities in the code.  It looks like Org just does a search/replace for the variable/value; if I happen to use the same name… again, it just feels like a hack :) Thanks, though :)

Comment: No problem, sorry I couldn't of been of more assistance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the problem is simply that you are using two different ways of specifying the language of the source blocks: `emacs-lisp` for some and `elisp` for others.  It seems that all the `elisp` blocks are tangled before all the `emacs-lisp` ones (alphabetical order?).  If you consistently use one or the other, then the order of the blocks in your file is respected:

```org
#+PROPERTY: tangle "init.el"
#+PROPERTY: noweb yes

* A
#+begin_src emacs-lisp
; initialization code
; this *must* come first
#+end_src

* B
#+begin_src emacs-lisp
<<support-functions>>
#+end_src

** Cool Stuff
#+begin_src emacs-lisp :noweb-ref "support-functions" :tangle no
(message "willkommen")
#+end_src

** Test
#+begin_src emacs-lisp :noweb-ref "support-functions" :tangle no
(message "hi")
#+end_src
```

tangles to

```el
; initialization code
; this *must* come first

(message "willkommen")
(message "hi")
```

Answer (score 4):

There are two problems here. The first is that you are setting the `tangle` property on the whole
document. When you do this, you need to set every block that is a
noweb block as `:tangle no`. It's much easier to set the `tangle`
property on one block and use it as a framework for the entire tangled
document. You can see how this works in my example below.

The second problem is your inconsistent source type declarations. the
`elisp` blocks are coming out first because they collate before
`emacs-lisp`. They should all be labelled the same if they are the
same language and go in the same file (there are exceptions, of
course, such as embedding SQL in PHP or something, but following my
first suggestion will help avoid problems.

```org
* A

#+header: :tangle init.el
#+header: :noweb yes
#+begin_src emacs-lisp
  ; initialization code
  ; this *must* come first

  <<support-functions>>
#+end_src

* B

** Cool Stuff

#+name: support-functions
#+begin_src emacs-lisp
  (message "willkommen")
#+end_src

** Test

#+name: support-functions
#+begin_src emacs-lisp
  (message "hi")
#+end_src
```

Tangles to

```el
; initialization code
; this *must* come first

(message "willkommen")
(message "hi")
```